# Is there a script to replay the portal credits in the computer terminal?

Tags: portal

As said in the question title, I'm searching a script/C/C++ program/whatever to replay the ending song of portal. I mean the whole terminal style credit playing as an application on the computer, not within Portal.

Comment: When you say "replay", do you mean something that mimics it, or something that actually launches the scene in Portal?

Comment: @Gnoupi: Edited his question for clarification (and provided answer).

Comment: I mean someone who coded that using ncurses or something like that. Because I find it awesome and I would like to know how they did it :)

Comment: Cool question... but not really about gaming.

Comment: Well I guess it's not programming either... It's kind of a mix of two and I guess only gamers know what I'm talking about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about here:

Download link: http://gaddc11.googlepages.com/stillaliveextra.rar
Source code: https://sites.google.com/site/gaddc11/Stillalive.rar?attredirects=0&d=1
YouTube video of it:

Official Source code in HTML/Java. Port to C+ from here? https://github.com/xBytez/aperturescience

Comment: Made my day sir, I'll have fun with that :)

Comment: Hmmm... The source code is SO UGLY xD I'll take it though. Thanks again.

Comment: @Depado: That's just the first search result I found, there might be better ones around. I only checked that the links were active, I've not looked at the source (or ran the program).